# iOS swift json PUT request string array in parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm working with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.
I'm trying to make a request with the following structure

```
{
    "email":"ppp@ppp.com",
    "password":"pppppp",
    "categories": [
        {"id":"2"},
        {"id":"1"},
        {"id":"6"},
        {"id":"5"}       
        ]
}
```

I'm using :

```
let parameters = [     
                       "email" : userEmail,
                  "categories" : userPassword,
                  "categorias" : selectedCategoriesArray]
```

`//where selectedCategoriesArray is a [[String]]()`

I fill my selectedCategoriesArray in a loop with this line modifying the array:

```
selectedCategoriesArray.append(["id", "2"]) //where 2 can be any other number

Alamofire.request( .PUT, url, parameters)
```

It seems it's working fine but it isn't, I don't know if my String array is taking the right format to be sent to the WS or do I need to encode it in a special way?

Has anyone worked with something like this, A little help would be appreciate. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your array should have a type of `[[String: String]]` in this case.

```
let userEmail = "myemail@email.com"
let userPassword = "123456"

var selectedCategoriesArray: [[String: String]] = []
for i in 0...5 {
  selectedCategoriesArray.append(["id": String(i)])
}

let parameters = [
  "email" :      userEmail,
  "password" :   userPassword,
  "categories" : selectedCategoriesArray
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with below

```
let savedData = ["id": 1, "id": 2]

let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "email": “xyz@yopmail.com”,
    "password": 123456,
    "categories": savedData
]

let valid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject) // true
```